# Salt Cloud Map File to Map Data

Tags: vmware-vsphere, saltstack, provisioning, salt-cloud

I'm trying to deploy a server using Salt cloud and the VMWare provider and I have developed a profile and a map file that works fine. I see however that there is a salt cloud module that might fit my use case better and I can call `salt MYSALTCLOUDSERVER cloud.map_run map_data='<actual map data>'`s from the salt master.

My problem is that I would like to convert my map file to map_data but I'm not sure of the format. Here is my map file:

```
SOMEPROFILE:
  - HOSTNAME:
      folder: 'FOLDERNAME'
      devices:
        network:
          Network adapter 1:
            ip: 'IPADDRESS'
```

Would anyone know what this would look like as map_data?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is

`{"SOMEPROFILE":[{"HOSTNAME":{"folder":"FOLDERNAME","devices":{"network":{"Network adapter 1":{"ip":"IPADDRESS"}}}}}]}`